# Eclipse does not recognize some coda-parts

Tags: android

Sorry for the unspecific title, but I do not know how to formulate it.

I have the following problem:

I Have installed Android SDK on my laptop and on another PC. I have to work on both PC. When transport a Project form my Laptop, I sometimes get the problem, that on the PC, parts of the code get the XXX cannot be resolved to a type.

Example: The Code is not so interesting, the problem is in the line, "AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);"

```
package com.example.alertdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlertDialog extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final int DIALOG_DELETE_YES_NO_MESSAGE = 1;
    public static final int DIALOG_DELETE_ALL_MESSAGE = 2;

    public class ExampleApp extends Activity {
            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setMessage("Do you want to close this window ?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    // Action for 'Yes' Button
    }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //  Action for 'NO' Button
    dialog.cancel();
    }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    // Title for AlertDialog
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    // Icon for AlertDialog
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alert.show();
    }
}
```

}

In another case, extend a class from a BaseAdapter. On the Laptop, I can overwrite functions like "getVIew", on the PC, there is an Error if I use "@Override".

This is the error I get: "Multiple markers at this line
    - implements android.widget.Adapter.getView
    - The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) of type ImageAdapter must override a superclass 
     method"

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too.  I found this link:
http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/re-import-android-project-issue.html

Basically, as he explains:

> Eclipse is defaulting to Java 1.5 and you have classes implementing interface methods (which in Java 1.6 can be annotated with @Override, but in Java 1.5 can only be applied to methods overriding a superclass method).
>
> Go to your project/ide preferences and set the java compiler level to 1.6 and also make sure you select JRE 1.6 to execute your program from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the android build target. Right click the project (in the left Package explorer in Eclipse) and choose Properties, tab Android and check that a Android SDK is selected. Click Apply.

Comment: Hi,under Properties->Android it looks exactly the same as it in my working project on the laptop. Under Projekt Build target, Android 2.3.1 is marked. That should be correct,or?